# When converting ts files to js I got a file not found error

Tags: bash, shell

command I run:

```
find app/ -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/.js$/.ts/'
```

Error I got:

```
xargs: rename: No such file or directory
```

If you know why I got this please tell me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or typescript. Shell command is where you are looking for help, it seems. I have changed the tags as a result. Also, what are you trying to achieve? What use is `'s/.js$/.ts/'` ?

Comment: Your `rename` is obviously broken, there's nothing wrong with your command. Try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

From **js** to **ts**

- Using **rename**

```
find app -type f -name '*.js' -print -exec rename .ts .js '{}' \+
```

- Using **mv**

```
find app -type f -name '*.js' -print -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv "$f" "${f%.*}.ts"' \;
```

From **ts** to **js**

- Using **rename**

```
find app -type f -name '*.ts' -print -exec rename .js .ts '{}' \+
```

- Using **mv**

```
find app -type f -name '*.ts' -print -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv "$f" "${f%.*}.js"' \;
```

Comment: It says this type of error : find: ‘rename’: No such file or directory

Comment: Wow! you replied after 6 days. That error says that you don't have `rename` command installed on your system. You can also use `mv` command if you have one but the above command needs to be changed sightly.

Comment: One more thing, do you want to rename `js` to `ts` or `ts` to `js`?